# How to make html list scrollable downwards on fullscreen page?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to put a list, that is scrollable, inside a div. My content takes up 100% of the page.

I use this code for my list:

```
ul {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

However when I add items to the list, it expands beyond the page size and it continues on even after the true `100%` of the page (being 768px in full screen for me) is used up. You can see it **not** working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BDUMw/7/

If you copy `<li>` several times, you will see that `<ul>` is extending further below the page.

How can I make the following CSS work within the `100%` page with `hidden overflow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `overflow-y:scroll;` in your `#contacts_container` CSS.

Here's a JSFiddle to show it. http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/JGssW/

Comment: FF24: http://habrastorage.org/storage3/8cc/cc9/abe/8cccc9abe4d08e9c08a8ee72fed21bb6.png

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I noticed that. I use Chrome for most everything so when I tested it in FF I noticed. I'm working on a possible solution now :]

Comment: I spent a day trying to figure it out. Good thing: I am not trying to make it work on IE :)